# Display one Column as Multiple Columns

Tags: crystal-reports

I have Table Structure Like 
[image]

I am Using Visual Studio 2013 and Crystal Report 13.0.12

Comment: use a cross tab for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Cross Tab for this, but you'll get more freedom by not using one:

In your report, group by Customer Name, then by TestName. Suppress all 5 of these sections *except* for the Group Footer of Customer Name. Here, place Customer Name, Result, and a new formula named Sugar. And inside sugar put this code:

```
PREVIOUS({Result})
```

Assuming there's no other TestNames besides Protein and Sugar, and assuming every Customer has one value for each, you should get the desired results in the footer. Let me know if that's the case and I can update the answer to accommodate.